# how to synchronized getUserMedia callbacks in a Singleton

Tags: javascript, html, callback, synchronization, getusermedia

I'm using a Singleton to get an audio recorder but getUserMedia is asynchronous and I must wait the callbacks end to return the recorder object. It's probably not a good choice to mix synchronous and asynchronous but I don't see how I can do because I can't make getUserMedia synchronous.

The idea is to call SoundRecorder.getInstance() which is going to ask the user to allow the microphone access one for all and to be able to get the recorder instance any time I need.

The problem is at the first call:
var recorder = SoundRecorder.getInstance();
recorder value is "undefined" then it works fine for the other calls.

This is my code below. Thanks for your help.

var SoundRecorder = (function() {

```
var instance = null;

function init () {

    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    if (instance == null) {
        navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true},
            function(stream) {
                var audioContext = new AudioContext();
                var input = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
                console.log('Media stream created.');

                input.connect(audioContext.destination);
                console.log('Input connected to audio context destination.');

                instance = new Recorder(input);
                dfd.resolve('recorder created');

            },
            function (e) {
                dfd.reject('No live audio input');
                notify('error', 'No live audio input: ' + e);
            });
    } else {
        dfd.resolve('recorder already created');
    }
    return dfd.promise();
}

function waitFor(p){
    if (p.state() == "resolved" || p.state() == "rejected") {
        return instance;
    } else {
        setTimeout(waitFor, 500, p);
    }
}

return {
    getInstance: function() {
        var promise = init();

        promise.then(function () {
            console.log('init success');
        }, function () {
            console.log('init failed');
        });

        return waitFor(promise);
    }
}
```

})();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I gave up using the singleton to only use call backs. I made the trick to just call getUserMedia once with an input hidden field that I use to handle different status: "enabled" if the user has allowed the microphone access, "disabled" if web audio not supported, "access" when the access is asked to the user. I think not so elegant but it works. I hope this can help somebody one day ;-)

Comment: samidarko - would you be willing to share the code for your solution, because I think it's exactly what I'm looking for!  Meanwhile, I'll try to recreate what you stated.